# Edit a XML using Notepad++ in a C# application

Tags: c#, xml, notepad++

I need to open and edit XML file using notepad++, I know how to open text file using savefileDilog but i need to get the Color coding which has in Notepad++ for XML coding, Please help me to do this, if i can get the colors for tags attributes in another way also OK.

Answer (score 0):

```
Process.Start( fullPathToNotePadPlusPlus, filename )
```

But you need full path to Notepad++, I'm not sure on the best way to get it.

The easiest for you might be to associate .xml files with notepad++.

Right click on an xml file, and do "Open With" --> "Choose default program"

Then set Notepad++ (you may need to browse for it )

Check "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file"

Then you could just do:

```
Process.Start( filename )
```

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ has the command line parameter -l for language, so you can run it with the syntax highlighting you want.

```
Process.Start(pathToNotepadExe, "-lxml [filename]");
```

see http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/command-line